# Writing bilevel TIFF Image with thumbnail in Java

Tags: javax.imageio, jai

I have  A0/E size bilevel TIFF Image with Group 4 Compression. I want to add/embed compressed thumbnail image. I need help for writing sequence structure for these images. Also Type and  recommended size of the thumbnail image

Thanks and Kind regards,
srinivasan

Comment: @haraldK  thanks, are we not supposed to use IFD 330 as per TIFF Specification Supplement 1?

Comment: Hmmm.. That might work. Not sure how good the software support for this kind of thumbnails is though (or how you even know it's a thumbnail, not just a "related image").